# Whonix problem with others IPs

Tags: whonix

I have a problem with two other IP addresses. Whonix-Workstation shows a different IP than the Gateway? Is it obliged to be this way?

My host OS is Kubuntu, and on it I have VirtualBox running whonix-gateway and whonix-workstation. The loaded Whonix-gateway shows a different IP than whonix-workstation. Should these two systems (gateway and workstation) not be associated with same IP address?

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Tor.SE. Can you please clarify your question or provide more information? Right now it's hard to tell what you're asking and your question was flagged as "low quality". For help asking questions, please see "[How do I ask a good question?](http://tor.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)" In the help center. I've temporarily blocked answers to prevent off-topic answers. I'll re-open once it's been clarified a bit. Thanks!

Comment: Do you got two different IP addresses and Whonix uses the wrong one or do you "just" see two different addresses?

Comment: @Lump: Please edit your question instead of adding information to a comment. Also it is not clear how are the Whonix virtual machines connected. Do they use VirtualBox NAT and DHCP server? Where are the IP addresses? Does every of the machines contain a single virtual ethernet interface with the IP address on it?

Comment: Reopened. More information would still be good, but this might be enough for someone to actually answer the question. In future, please edit your question instead of adding clarification in the comments. For now I've migrated the text for you. Thanks again; I hope you find the answer you're looking for!

Comment: Where does it show different IPs? In whonixcheck? Well, then that's normal. This is due to Tor [Stream Isolation](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Stream_Isolation). Or are you wondering why Whonix-Gateway's own traffic is routed over Tor as well? This has [different reasons](https://www.whonix.org/w/index.php?title=Template:TorifiedGateway&action=edit) and would be worth another question.

Answer (score 1):

Your two Whonix VMs should NOT have the same IP address, the Whonix gateway should be able to see its own external IP address simply because it has to connect to the internet to do its job; however, the Whonix workstation should never be able to find the public IP because its only connection is to a second (internal only) IP of the Whonix gateway.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what IP addresses OP is referring to.

The Whonix gateway has two adapters. One adapter (eth0) may connect to the VirtualBox host, or to a router VM. It will report (using ifconfig) whatever IP address the corresponding DHCP server gives it.

The other adapter of the Whonix gateway (eth1) connects to a VirtualBox internal network (by default, "whonix") which it shares with the workstation. The gateway and workstation (obviously) have different local IP addresses on that internal network. By default, the gateway is 192.168.0.10, and the workstation is 192.168.0.11 (both static).

As adrelanos notes, Whonix uses stream isolation, so each isolated application will have a unique public IP address via Tor. However, because the workstation connects through the gateway, particular applications running on either should report the same IP address at any given time, until the circuit changes.

Firewall and routing rules on the gateway prevent local applications from accessing anything via eth0 except through Tor.